# Python/Pygame movement incrementation

Tags: python, pygame

I have a board of 11 spaces. I have a counter and a dice also. I want the player to hit "a" and it takes the "coordY - 72 * diceRoll" This will move them for example 2 spaces up the board if they roll a 2. When it's their turn to roll again and say for example they roll a 3 this time, in total they would have moved 5 spaces up the board from the starting position. the problem is when they roll for example a two they move two spaces up, and then when they roll for example a 3 it only moves to space 3 not 5. So it doesn't save the previous position and move it from there. I have no idea how i'd do this.
Here's my current code:

```
    countY = 750
    count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(150, countY), 25, 0)
    count2 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(250, countY), 25, 0)
    count3 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(450, countY), 25, 0)
    count4 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(550, countY), 25, 0)
    print("Should draw start counters")
    pygame.display.flip()



def movement():

    pygame.display.update()

    while True:
        global countY
        game = True
        while game:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                pygame.event.get()

                #Counter 1 movement
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
                    window.fill(grey)
                    grid()
                    count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(150, countY - 72 * diceRoll), 25, 0)
                    countY= countY - 72 * diceRoll # here is where the countY is updated
                    game = False
                    game2 = True
                    print("Test")
```

Comment: Which variable is supposed to store the updated value `5` ?

Comment: I dunno, I thought that countY would :/

Comment: If `countY` is supposed to store it then its not updated...can you link me to complete code (pastebin,etc)

Comment: Sorry, i'm not comfortable with giving out all of my code, so here's a screen shot. http://imgur.com/Gj1f0AH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your problem...
then you need to make `countY` as global but inside the `movement()` function where it is updated not outside.

Also if `countY` changes by `(countY - 72 * diceRoll)`  every time a dice is rolled so you need to update it which you obviously are missing.

```
countY=750

def movement
    while True:
        global countY #declare global here
        game = True
        while game:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                #Counter 1 movement
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
                    window.fill(grey)
                    grid()
                    count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(150, countY - 72 * diceRoll), 25, 0)
                    countY= countY - 72 * diceRoll # here is where the countY is updated
                    game = False
                    game2 = True
                    print("Test")
```

this is when all players score is combined and updated.
but if you want each players own score to be updated when He/She rolls a dice then you can use separate variables for each of them

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out now, I'll let you know how it goes. Never the less thanks anyway.

Comment: This is what it is like now, but it's saying countY is not defined? (I'll place the update in the main question)

Comment: is the code above the function `movement()` indented because it is a part of other function?
If yes then you need to declare `countY` to be global in every function you are using it

Comment: Yes it is another function

Comment: I fixed it! :D Thanks ever so much buddy, I've been trying to fix it for weeks now, who knew it could be so simple. Le sigh. Thanks.

Comment: I've found an issue, if you could look at this video you'll see the problem, thanks: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFyAXW8nt1o&feature=youtu.be

Comment: you mean separate moves for black and separate moves for white players.
Not combined...If that's the case then you need two variables lets say:
`countY1` and `countY2` one for black and one for white...
and update `countY1` when a black moves and update `countY2` if white moves